# Ios - Is there a way to draw a line in UIViewController without using code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to draw a line in UIViewController without using code, so like the constraints for the lines can be given in storyboard itself. if there is a way to do it, please tell me. Now i have drawn a line by placing an UIView in storyboard and used the following code to draw line on it. Is this the best way ?. Or do i have any better way ?. Thanks in advance.

```
class line: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let aPath = UIBezierPath()

        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:1))

        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:500, y:1))

        //Keep using the method addLineToPoint until you get to the one where about to close the path

        aPath.close()

        //If you want to stroke it with a red color
        UIColor.blue.set()
        aPath.stroke()
        //If you want to fill it as well
        aPath.fill()
    }
}
```

Using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.2

Comment: Just give this view a height of 1 or 0.5 in storyboard

Comment: Just use UIView with height of 1.

Comment: Nice idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@IBDesignable` as follows. Make your view with height of one as suggested and the @IBDesignable will show your line in your storyboard.:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class line: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let aPath = UIBezierPath()
        aPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1))
        aPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 250, y: 1))
        aPath.close()
        UIColor.blue.set()
        aPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, use Upper case class names :-)

Comment: Quite right :) was just carrying the original poster's class name forward though.

Comment: Sorry, missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Add a UIView with a height of 1 point. 
Add constraints for it.